# How do you ignore '\' at the end of a string in C

Tags: c

I have a string argument like so

```
 ./blah "slkf\"
```

And I want to manipulated the string argument, "slkf\", without the prompt opening on the next line in Terminal. How do you do this?

Comment: This isn't a C problem that can be solved in the `blah` program.  This is a shell problem.

Answer (score 6):

Use another backslash to escape it:

```
./blah "slkf\\"
```